# Nested Divs housing a responsive image slideshow script in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to remove the space below the nested divs housing a jquery slideshow from iosscripts, in a wordpress page. My images are double sized 1000px resized with height: 500px;

All seems well except I can't seem to remove the space from below the slideshow so I can have paragraph text directly underneath. In Safari all seems well.

Here is the CSS in question and web address below that.

```
.responsiveHeight {
   position: relative;
   height: 0;
   overflow: visible;
   padding: 0 0 40%;
}
.responsiveHeight > .inner {
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}

.iosSlider {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
}

.iosSlider .slider {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
}

.iosSlider .slider img {
   vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   height: 100% !important;
   max-height: 500px;
   width: auto;
}
```

http://jbaphotography.co.uk/newsite/business-proposal-tender-photography/

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your the padding of 40% on the class

```
.responsiveHeight {
   position: relative;
   height: 0;
   overflow: visible;
   padding: 0 0 40%;
  }
```

adjust that padding a little lower and it should give you the desired look

Comment: so so simple... thanks very much. I completely missed that. Couldn't see the wood for the trees!